# Server 2012 R2 Standard w/ 2 users RDP in, won't allow administrator to log in on server without knocking someone off

Tags: windows-server-2012

What can I do so that the administrator can log into the server without knocking off the 2 RDP users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a licensing question: The standard (built-in) terminal services license allows for 2 concurrent connections and is intended for administration tasks only. If an RDP session in this mode to use it as a desktop without administrative intent is legal or not depends on many factors including the jurisdiction.

To allow for more concurrent users and non-administrative tasks, you need to purchase additional licenses and make them known to the licensing services control panel. This will lift the concurrency level to the licensed number.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as you can no longer RDP to the console session (which is what you used to do in older versions.).